# Fedora 38 ARM on Raspberry Pi. Installation wizard not coming up

Tags: fedora, raspberry-pi, arm

I’ve installed Fedora Phosh 38 (latest version won’t work with any display) on Raspberry Pi 4, CM4 to be exact, and after first boot I’ve been welcomed with a login screen.
But I don’t have the username and password. After some initial research I’ve found out that after the first boot it should run into installation wizard and not boot directly into login screen.

I tried to flash it several times but always with the same result.

Does anyone have any experience with this combination?

In other case I wonder if it would be possible to chroot to the image and create new user manually.

Thanks in advance.